# Android to IOS direct conversion

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native

just to expand my knowledge , Why do we need a separate platform like react-native, flutter to create cross platform mobile apps ? isn't there a way to convert the android code directly to IOS ?

Comment: No there is not, you would have to build 2 seperate Apps if you dotn wanna use a cross platform Framework!

Comment: any idea why isn't there anything like that yet ?

Comment: Because the operating systems work differently its just not possible to convert the code and expect it to run.